# A non well formed numeric value encountered in laravel 5.5 and am using php 7.2

Tags: php, laravel

```
echo  ('john'.'_'.str_replace('.',time(),microtime()*rand()));
```

i am using php laravel *5.5* and  my php version is *7.2*

Also I have tried:

```
composer update
```

and:

```
composer update symfony/var-dumper
```

but the problem still occurs.

Comment: microtime looks like this 0.36531400 1522584302 therefore you can'd do microtime()*rand(). A simple google search or var_dump(microtime()) would have given you the answer

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is appears in `microtime()`. It returns something like `0.13685800 1522584183`. There is space among of them. Because of this product of `microtime()` and `*rand()` can't be calculated.

You must get first or second part of `microtime()`:

For first part:

```
echo ('john'.'_'.str_replace('.',time(),explode(' ',microtime())[1]*rand()));
```

For second part:

```
echo ('john'.'_'.str_replace('.',time(),explode(' ',microtime())[2]*rand()));
```

`explode()` function splits string to 2 part and return this parts as array.

Comment: Thanks! it is solved now . but my code was working in php 5.6 and in laravel 5.4 and i there only 40 to 50 characters long string but now in php 7.2 its too long . what is that can you please explain it

Comment: Code that I give you above returns `john_1701933534062387032` in PHP 7.2.3. What do you want to mean by `its too long` ? Can you write some example please?